# How to get this effect?

Tags: shaders

how to do exactly the same effect? I tried with transmissions, etc., and I cannot find the right shader.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I took the *Color* output of a *Noise Texture* and multiplied it by itself, and then cranked the *Saturation*.  Feed it into both a *Principled Volume* and a *Principled BSDF* with a low *Alpha* value.

[image]

To match your photo you will probably have to mess with the *Alpha* and *Density* a little more than I have.